# profile a forked process using pycharm

Tags: python, multiprocessing, profiling, pycharm

is it possible to profile a forked process within pycharm?
simply the main process spawns a few other processes and I need to profile the child process. It seems by default the pycharm profiler only profiles the main process.

Comment: Is there a Youtrack issue for this filed?